# Execute a project consisting of multiple maven projects in drop wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, dropwizard

I working in Dropwizard and I have boilerplate for production-ready development in Dropwizard. When import the project the project gets split into multiple maven projects, then when I build the project multiple jar file one for each maven project is produced. when I run any jar file I get missing artifact error. How can I execute it as one package on the server? 
[image]

Comment: "When import the project the project gets split into multiple maven projects" Import into what? Eclipse doesn't split projects.

Comment: I imported one maven project and I got that what you can see in the project explorer panel. What should I do to execute the whole thing?

Comment: Does adding the required projects in the launch configuration solve your issue(_Run > Run Configurations_, in _Dependencies_ tab click _Add Projects..._)? If yes, you can add the required projects to the Java build path of the project.

Comment: How do you execute them(the jars created), what error do you get? How are these modules related to each other?

Comment: I got it to work, I was missing the Application class in my module!